# ng-click in the directive doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to execute a function when clicking on a checkbox but nothing happens.

When I put the `sendMediaToScreen` function in the link (`scope.sendMediaToScreen()`), the function works, so it's OK with the `scope`.

```
.directive('uxEmbedVideo', ['$compile','myURL', function( $compile, myURL ) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            'clientId': '@',
            'sendMediaToScreen': '&',
            'rule': '=',
            'screenActivated' : '='
        },
        link: function( scope, element, attrs ){
        },
        templateUrl: myURL.getAppViewsPath() + '/partials/embed-video.html'
    };
}])
```

**Directive**

```
<ux-embed-video
    rule="user.rules"
    screen-activated="room.parameters.screenActivated"
    send-media-to-screen="roomManager.sendMediaToScreen({ clientId : user.clientId, from: 'producer' })">
</ux-embed-video>
```

**/partials/embed-video.html**

```
<div class="ux-video-admin-controls" ng-if="rule === 'administrator'" >
    <input ng-if="screenActivated"
       restrict access="administrator"
       class="ux-admin-videoToScreen"
       type="checkbox"
       ng-click="sendMediaToScreen()"
       />
</div>
```

Comment: could you provide fiddle/plunkr?

Comment: So you are saying, `roomManager.sendMediaToScreen` is not executed?

Comment: Where is your binding inside the directive?
You should bind the element to the click event.

Comment: yes , but when i put scope.sendMediaToScreen() in the link's directive, the function is executed immediately

Comment: @ ShacharW : 'sendMediaToScreen': '&', in the scope definition is not binding ?

Comment: @DavidAuvray: Yes, but there also should be something like:
element.bind('click', function(){})

Comment: Maybe you need - $event.stopPropagation();

Comment: @ ShacharW : element.bind('click', function(){
                   console.log('foo');
               })   doesn't work ....

Comment: Something is wrong with your setup, posted code seems to work fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/i7aZEuSMFYHkyqQvn4Dg?p=preview

Comment: thanks, I just answer the question below. I knew that this example would work but I noticed that my html could be the cause. an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem lies within the usage of your `<ux-embed-video>` directive.

You are binding the result of `roomManager.sendMediaToScreen({ clientId : user.clientId, from: 'producer' })` to `scope.send-media-to-screen` instead of passing in a callback.

Comment: oO ... ok but can you give me a little example, i don't understand, thanks

Comment: You don't seem to understand the purpose of the `&` config. The way OP is using is totally correct and fine. Infact posted code works fine, so the problem is in OP's setting project somewhere. See it working: http://plnkr.co/edit/i7aZEuSMFYHkyqQvn4Dg?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but replacing the template directive like this, now it works

**in the directive :**

remove -> replace: true,

**in the template**

```
<div class="ux-video-admin-controls" ng-if="rule === 'administrator' && screenActivated" >
    <input
       restrict access="administrator"
       class="ux-admin-videoToScreen"
       type="checkbox"
       ng-click="sendMediaToScreen()"
       />
</div>
```

Thank you